# Symfony 2.8: Trying to register custom bundle in AppKernel throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, namespaces, composer-php, symfony-2.8

I started working with Symfony and was attempting to add a reusable bundle. To achieve so I did following: 
1.did *app/console generate:bundle*, here is the console output

```
Bundle namespace: Wyzen/DocumentUploader
 The namespace must end with Bundle. 
Bundle namespace: Wyzen/DocumentUploaderBundle

In your code, a bundle is often referenced by its name. It can be the
concatenation of all namespace parts but it's really up to you to come
up with a unique name (a good practice is to start with the vendor name).
Based on the namespace, we suggest WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle.

Bundle name [WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle]: WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle

Bundles are usually generated into the src/ directory. Unless you're
doing something custom, hit enter to keep this default!

Target Directory [src/]: vendor/

What format do you want to use for your generated configuration?

Configuration format (annotation, yml, xml, php) [xml]: yml


  Bundle generation  


> Generating a sample bundle skeleton into vendor/Wyzen/DocumentUploaderBundle OK!
> Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
> Enabling the bundle inside app/AppKernel.php: OK
> Importing the bundle's routes from the app/config/routing.yml file: OK
```

Then I created a composer json inside the bundle root with following content:

```
{
    "name": "wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader",
    "description": "A test bundle",
    "type": "library",
    "version":"dev-master",
    "source": {
        "url": "https://github.com/xyz/wyzen-document-uploader",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Wyzen\\DocumentUploaderBundle\\": ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir": "Wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@xyz.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}
```

Now after successfully installing this bundle in another application using composer.

I added following line to register my bundle in AppKernel.php

```
new Wyzen\DocumentUploaderBundle\WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle()
```

Upon which it throws the this exception

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 40: Attempted to load
>   class "WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle" from namespace
>   "Wyzen\DocumentUploaderBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

Comment: "Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED" might be a clue.  Ask yourself how the autoloader is supposed to find your code.

Comment: Please do not write (or generate) custom code inside the `vendor` directory. This directory is managed by Composer and should not be part of your version control system (e.g. git).

Comment: @Cerad it would be helpful if you answer questions with answers rather raising more questions :)

Comment: @xabbuh I have not written anything inside vendor directory. i have used composer.json to install my custom made library. Neither, vendor is part of version control here. Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: According to the command output you were generating the bundle inside the `vendor` directory.

Comment: @xabbuh yes you are correct. But i did not really do anything else there except generating the bundle. Finally i have used that code using composer only.

Answer (score 1):

All that your describe is correct.
I install your bundle and it's work.

```
$ composer require wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader
Using version dev-master for wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader     
...          
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader (dev-master master): Cloning master from cache
```

Check

```
$ composer info -i
...
wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader        dev-master master A test bundle
```

Registering bundle

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            // ...
            new Wyzen\DocumentUploaderBundle\WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle(),
        ]
```

Check

```
php bin/console debug:config WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle

Current configuration for "WyzenDocumentUploaderBundle"
=======================================================

wyzen_document_uploader: {  }
```

To fix your problem, try to rebuild the autoloader :

```
composer run-script post-update-cmd
```

Or retry a fresh install

Comment: Didn't help.

Throws following

 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                             
   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Wyzen\DocumentUploaderBundle\DocumentUploaderBundle' not found in /private/var/www/html/go4world/go4web/app/AppKernel.php on line 40

Comment: Did you see your package into /private/var/www/html/go4world/go4web/vendor ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Entire directory was there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the problem by adding **classmap** under autoload tree to the composer json and passing the path to the class directory in the main project.

```
 "classmap": [
        "vendor/wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader"
 ]
```

Comment: You don't install your package with composer. If you have follow the previous post your package will be installed under vendor/wyzen/wyzen-document-uploader (according with your bundle composer.json) not under vendor/amanangira/document-uploader-bundle

Comment: @EquaPro I have updated the answer with the correct path. Sorry for the wrong path mentioned earlier.